# Zend Framework strange content

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Hi, I have this `Zend_Form` and it's value get changed.
My input text in the form gets modified like for example:
instead of the text `It's a great day` I get `It\'s a great day`

I use

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setRequired(true);
$name->setFilters(array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'));
$name->setDecorators(array(
    'Errors',
    'viewHelper',
));
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to your PHP uses magic quoting.

Check if `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` returns TRUE. If it does then `\ ' " &` chars in GET and POST request data will get escaped with `\`.

To counter that you must use additional filter function like `stripslashes()` or follow this example to do it properly in Zend Framework:
http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2008/10/zend-framework-forms-and-magic_quotes_gpc/

// Appendix:

On your local machine you can do what the **Sudhir** explained in his answer, but on a shared hosting that might not be possible unless you have access to `php.ini` file or PHP is loaded as `Apache` module (mod_php/mod_php5)

Comment: ok i've checked the function get_magic_quotes_gpc() and it returns 1 so that means it's active, i also have this piece of code if ( ! is_php('5.4') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
   $str = stripslashes($str);
  }

Comment: i used the $form->populate() and this into my header   $this->view->setEscape('stripslashes'); and now it works fine for the form but in rest it's the same. When i list the records from database it's getting the slash again.

Comment: Well, unless you prevent magic quotes with `php.ini` setting `$_GET` and `$_POST` (and `$_REQUEST`) superglobals will contain slashed values. As for DB, it seems to me that the value was saved in slashed form. To fix that you should update db with stripslashed values.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **php.ini** file and look for a setting called **magic_quotes_gpc** and set it to Off. You could set it to off thru **.htaccess** file as well,

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```

Comment: i have put in my php.ini file this magic_quotes_gpc = Off and still the same

Comment: check out this link:: http://www.pablumfication.co.uk/2010/05/28/zend_form-apply-zend_filter-to-all-form-elements/  this might get you the solution

Comment: @alex Did you restarted the apache server? Php.ini settings changes will be applied only after apache restart if running php as a apache module